# viable geothermal energy supply from exhausted fracked gas wells?

Tags: geology, geothermal-heat, economic-geology, fracking

The UK legislator with primary responsibility for energy has claimed that exhausted fracked natural-gas wells will be suitable for re-use as a geothermal energy supply (not necessarily geothermal for electricity production, but rather for heat distribution, so let's say 80° - 250°C).

Is there much of a co-location of the geo-thermal resource in the UK, with the more easily obtained frackable natural gas; and would an exhausted fracked well be structurally suitable for this?

Comment: Just want to connect with [this related question](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2845/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-depleted-oil-wells-for-geothermal-production).

Answer (score 4):

Viability of an oil or gas well for geothermal energy production is dependent upon several factors:
 - Geothermal heat profile with depth near the well 
 - Depth of the exhausted well
 - Volume of fluid acting as a heat exchange around and near the well.

I think it might be possible to use exhausted natural-gas wells will be suitable for re-use as a geothermal energy supply. Likelihood of success would require site investigation and the engineering pilot study.  This idea would be ideal for university engineering / geology research.

Comment: Presumably the fracking would increase near-well permeability, which would make it better (=higher effective volume) for a heat-exchange system?

Comment: Yes.  The fact is almost all oil, gas and water wells are fracked to increase production.